# Should your website work without JavaScript

Tags: javascript, browser

We're developing a web application that is going to be used by external clients on the internet. The browsers we're required to support are IE7+ and FF3+. One of our requirements is that we use AJAX wherever possible. Given this requirement I feel that we shouldn't have to cater for users without javascript enabled, however others in the team disagree.

My question is, if, in this day and age, we should be required to cater for users that don't have javascript enabled?

Comment: I know this is an old question but I would think that you would want to go to the company you are doing the job for and see how their IT set the computers up.(if the biz is large enough to have IT department)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Coming back more than 10 years later, it's worth noting my first two bullet points have faded to insignificance, and the situation has improved marginally for the third (accessible browsers do better) and fourth (Google runs more js) as well.

---

There are a lot more users on the public internet who may have trouble with javascript than you might think:

- Mobile browsers (smartphones) often have very poor or buggy javascript implementations.  These will often show up in statistics on the side of those that *do* support javascript, even though they in effect don't. This is getting better, but there are still lots of people stuck with old or slow android phones with very old versions of Chrome or bad webkit clones.
- Things like NoScript are becoming more popular, so you should at least have a nice initial page for those users.
- If your customer is in any way part of the U.S. Goverment, you are legally required to support screen readers, which typically don't do javascript, or don't do it well.
- Search engines will, *at best*, only run a limited set of your javascript. You want to work well enough without javascript to allow them to still index your site.

Of course, you need to know your audience.  You might be doing work for a corporate intranet where you *know* that *everyone* has javascript (though even here I'd argue there's a growing trend where these sites are made available to teleworkers with unknown/unrestricted browsers). Or you might be building an app for the blind community where *no one* has it. In the case of the public internet, you can typically figure about 95% of your users will support it in some fashion (source cited by someone else in one of the links below). That number sounds pretty high, but it can be misleading; turn it around, and if you don't support javascript you're turning away 1 visitor in 20.

See these:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121108/how-many-people-disable-javascript
- [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822872/do-web-sites-really-need-to-cater-for-browsers-that-dont-have-javascript-enabled>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822872/do-web-sites-really-need-to-cater-for-browsers-that-dont-have-javascript-enabled%3E)

Comment: I think I read that the Google spider actually does run javascript, but I can't find the link at the moment.

Comment: I believe it only runs trivial things like document.write()

Comment: As of 2016, screen readers and the Google crawler run Javascript.

Comment: I would not say that second bullet point "faded to insignificance". If anything, it became even more relevant than before to use things like NoScript. I use NoScript cause lots of website are running scripts that have absolutely nothing to do with the site itself, like some banking websites can run js from facebook. Facebook has nothing to do with my banking.

Answer (score 9):

You should weigh the options and ask yourself:

1) what percentage of users will have javascript turned off.  (according to [this site](http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_stats.asp), only 5% of the world has it turned off or not available.)
2) will those users be willing to turn it on
3) of those that aren't willing to turn it on, or switch to another browser or device that has javascript enabled, is the lost revenue more than the effort to build a separate non-javascript version?

Instinctively, I say most times the answer is no, don't waste the time building two sites.

Comment: +1, unless a non-JS version is an actual requirement, deciding whether to support Javascript or not is a cost-benefit analysis.

Answer (score 5):

> My question is, if, in this day and age, we should be required to cater for users that don't have javascript enabled?

Yes, definitely, *if* the AJAX functionality is core to the working of your site. If you don't, you are effectively denying users who don't have Javascript enabled access to your website, and although this is a rather small proportion (<5% I believe), it means that they won't be able to use your site at all, because the core functions are not available to them.

Of course if you're doing more trivial things with AJAX that just enhance the user experience but are not actually central to the core functionality of the site, then this probably isn't necessary.

Comment: 2% or less disable JavaScript support according to Yahoo.  JavaScript support is as high as 99.75% in Brazil and lowest in the US at about 2%. http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2010/10/how-many-users-have-javascript-disabled/

Answer (score 3):

Depends really.

I personally switch off JavaScript all the time because I don't trust lots of sites.

However, since you users have explicitly asked for your application, you can assume they will trust it and there is no point in doing extra work.

More, if you have that strong AJAX-affinity requirement, the question seems odd enough.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit like beating a dead horse, but I'll have a go at it, sure.

I think there could be two basic approaches to this:

1.

Using ajax (and, basically,
javascript) to enhance the experience
of the users, while making sure, that
all of the application's features
work without javascript.

When I am
   following this principle, I develop the
   interface in two phases - first
   without considering javascript at all
   (say, using a framework, that doesn't
   know about javascript) and then
   augment certain workflows by adding
   ajax-y validation (don't like pure js
   validation, sorry) and so on.

This means, if the user has javascript disabled, your app shall in no way break or become unusable for him.

2.

Using javascript to its fullest, "no javascript - no go" style. If javascript is not available, the user will not be able to use your application at all. It is important to note, that, in my opinion, there is no middle ground, - if you are trying to be in both worlds at once, you are doing too much extra work. Removing the constraints of supporting no-javascript users, obviously adds more opportunities to create a richer user experience. And it makes *creating* that experience much easier.

Comment: +1 This is really the way to go. If you start with building a site for users without javascript, the total work is not much more then building a site only for javascript users. On the other hand if you can't make the site usable without javascript, don't bother making it almost usable.

Answer (score 1):

I think that depends on the type of web application you are going to build. For example in an e-commerce application the checkout process should propably work without java script because there are some people who deactivate js for checking out (in our experience). In a web 2.0 application in my opinion it isn't necessary to support non-js browser experience. 
Developing for both also complicates the development process and is more cost intensive. you have double your web test efforts (testing with and without js) and also think different in the planning phase.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on the market segment you're aiming for, if you're going for a tech crowd -such as Stackoverflow.com, or perhaps slashdot- then you're probably fine in expecting users to have JS installed and active.

Other sites, with a medially tech-aware audience, may suffer from users knowing enough about JS-based exploits to have deactivated JS, but with not enough knowledge to enable Scriptblock (or other browser-equivalent).

The non-tech aware audience are probably with the tech-crowd, since they possibly just don't know how to disable JS -or why they may want to- regardless of the risk.

Answer (score 0):

In short, you should cater to *spiders* without JavaScript enabled, but only to the degree necessary to index the data that you want to expose to the public. Your browser requirements of IE7+ and FF3+ exclude far more people than the total number of people who disable JavaScript. And of those who do disable it, the vast majority know how to enable it when necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I asked myself the same question the other day and came up with the answer that in order to use my application one **must have Javascript enabled**. I also checked various Ajax powered sites. Even Stackoverflow.

But considering this fact I also believe that you do need to support some degree of *prehistoric* applications. The main idea is to not let application break when users don't have enabled Javascript. Application should still display relevant data, but its functionality would be limited.

Answer (score 0):

To add to some of the old discussion on this page. Google is now searching JavaScript: http://www.i-programmer.info/news/81-web-general/4248-google-now-searches-javascript.html

Answer (score -1):

This is an issue that I was thinking about just a few days ago. Here is some information

- In Google Chrome there is no way (menu/option) inside the browser to turn off Javascript.
- Many websites including those from leading names like Google, etc., will not work without Javascript.
- According to stats over 95% of visitors have Javascript enabled now.

These stats made me think. Do I have to break my back writing a lot of background code and everything for users who have disabled Javascript?

My conclusion was this. Yes, I have to include Javascript support, but not at the cost of sanity. I.e. I can afford to give it a low priority.

So I am going to have support for non-javascript browsing, but I will build most of it after my site is deployed.

Comment: At least in the current version of Chrome (24) you can switch off javascript completely in the settings.