# cakePHP: How to format time duration as MM:SS

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have an input in my form that needs to specify a length of time in minutes and seconds (not a specific date/time). How do I do this?

```
    echo $this->Form->input('time', array('type'=>'time', 'timeFormat'=>24));
    //results in HH:MM but I need MM:SS
```

Answer (score 1):

The default FormHelper does not support this, so you will have to use a regular 'text' input (`'type' => 'text'`) and parse/format the value in the `beforeValidate()` of your Model.

Alternatively, you can create two dropdowns (minutes and second), OR use a dateTime input and hide the non-relevant dropdowns with CSS, but this may a bit 'dirty'

You will also need to create a custom validation-rule to validate your value; see [Adding your own Validation Methods](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#adding-your-own-validation-methods), because the built-in 'time' validation rule does not validate seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I will rather prefer you to go for JS timepicker. Just add a the plugin to your porject and use its feature as per requirement listed in below link
http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-time-picker-plugins/

hope this will help!!

Comment: forget to mention that cakephp helper (form/html) does not support any this kind of facility like this rather you look for the Client or server side validation to accomplish the task. And Handling thing at first hand is best.. So implement the JS plugin with reducing the effort and time.

Comment: Client-side 'validation' is good practice if it improves the *user-experience* (e.g. directly telling a value is invalid without having to submit a form). But, **you should _never_ rely on client-side validation alone**. Simply disabling JavaScript will allow a user to enter anything he/she wants

Comment: today's almost all (famous) application (web) are mostly driven by Javascript (ajax/Jquery). Even without Jquery framework we cant imagine of developing an elegant and adequate application. Its obvious that user will face problem  If ** Javascript disabled** for whatsoever reason. So i think we should show them a viable message to show the error. And Yes we have to handle this by Server side validation too before facing application's unexpected behavior.

Comment: For example _Yahoo.com_ are using ajax based login credential validation.

Comment: I do not disagree on using jQuery/JavaScript for a website, but your last line is the major point of my previous comment. When developing an application, validation and security should be an important issue. *Don't* think you're done if a jQuery Widget shows a nice message that *"the date was invalid"* if your application still allows malformed dates because it's not validating

Comment: Regarding Yahoo; did you also notice what happens if you disable JavaScript? The site still works! Even StackOverflow works with JavaScript disabled. It's called [Progressive enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) or [Graceful degradation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fault-tolerant_system) depending on your viewpoint. Also read this question, although some years old, many things still apply. [Should your website work without JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1084065/should-your-website-work-without-javascript)

Comment: Yeah I got your point. Thank you `thaJeztah` I really learned a new thing.