# Do you still Hide from browsers that do not support JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Some of the examples I'm reading start with:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!-- Hide from browsers that do not support JavaScript
// --> Finish hiding
</script>
```

1. Do you still wrap your js code in html comments?
2. Do you still include language="javascript"?
3. Do you still include type="text/javascript"?

Comment: [No to 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507939/using-html-comment-tag-still-relevant-around-javascript-code/1508005#1508005) and [2, yes to 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.1).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do browsers today really not hide javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5743364/do-browsers-today-really-not-hide-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `<script>...</script>`

There is one more attribute available: `<script charset="utf-8">` Specifying a charset for a `SCRIPT` is useful only if it differs from the page. The page charset is defined in the `HEAD` tag by:
`<meta charset="..." />`

And in the quest of removing unnecessary things: To avoid the `onload`, `document...ready` and friends, just place the `SCRIPT` tag that starts your app at the end of the `BODY` tag. All JS files in the `HEAD` and the `DOM` are loaded and ready to be used.

```
  <html>
    <head>
      <script src="lib.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      ...
      <script>
        //start your app here
      </script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" /> is useless. Browsers were just looking for the charset so now in HTML 5, you've got a charset meta that works just the same even in older browsers.

Comment: @xavierm02, you're right I updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

1: No. The onload browsers that don't support JavaScript and still exist just ignore what's in the script tag.
2: No. It's depreciated. The only use what to say to IE you were using JavaScript and not VBScript but nowadays it just assumes it.
3: With HTML5, you don't need it anymore in order to pass the validator but even before, it was useless.
More informations : https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTML/Element/Script

The only one thing about script tags nowadays is you shouldn't use the stand-alone form.