# Is there any reason to build a website so that it can run with javascript disabled anymore?

Tags: javascript

For the longest time, one of the basic technical requirements for website projects I've worked on was that the site should run with javascript disabled.

It actually caused a great design by-product: concerns were nicely separated between basic functionality and user-experience improvements.  Beyond that, I don't know of any reason to do so anymore.

Assuming that I'm targeting the widest user base possible, are there any reasons not to make javascript required?

Comment: This may be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822872/do-web-sites-really-need-to-cater-for-browsers-that-dont-have-javascript-enable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a significant fraction of your user base (real or expected) — for whatever reason — browses with JS turned off, then *of course* your site should work well with JS disabled.

Comment: They don't necessarily need to have scripting turned off or unavailable, it could be that some part of the script fails. That is particularly relevant on the web since there are so many different devices and browsers that it is very likely that part of a script will fail in at least some of them. Providing a fallback to native browser capability means the page isn't reliant on all of the script executing in every environment that loads it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it depends upon your target audience and what portion of them you think might not have javascript or have it enabled.

And, you have to balance that with how useful/competitive your site could be without javascript.  If your site wouldn't be all that useful without dynamic capabilities or it would be ridiculously time consuming to make a whole new implementation of your site that didn't use javascript, then it may not make sense for you to do so, even if you were potentially losing 10% of your viewers.  It might make more sense to put all that development time into things that increase the value of your site for people that do have javascript.

So, it really depends upon tradeoffs that are particular to your specific site.

The one exception to all of this is that you typically need to make sure you can get good search relevance and most search bots that collect data for search indexing do not run javascript in any way so the data you want search indexed must be available without javascript.

Answer (score 0):

One good reason is that it provides for fallback. If feature testing shows a particular feature can't be implemented, then you just don't implement it knowing that the site will still work.

Of course scripting allows for more features in the UI, but providing basic functionality without any scripting is always a solid base to start from.

For example, a web site recently had it's comments section disabled because some clever designer thought it was a good idea to disable the submit button by default and only enable it when the user starts typing a comment. An upgrade to the library they were using cased the script to fail, so the button was left disabled and users couldn't submit comments.

That error would likely not happen if the page was designed to work without scripting by default and extra features added later.