# convention of javascript disabled

Tags: javascript, web-applications

I am building a website, and many part of it are built on JS.
I wanted to know what is the probability of users not having JS enabled, and what is the convention in web applications once such user enters the site.

do the sites writes a message (please enable JS), they do not do anything?

Thanks

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/822872/395760

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I wanted to know what is the probability of users not having JS enabled

It varies depending on the demographics who use the site.

Keep in mind that JS can fail for other reasons (such as network errors) then it being explicitly turned off by the user.

Some mobile networks, for instance, ["optimise" HTTP traffic in such a way that JavaScript sometimes breaks](http://www.orbific.com/weblog/2008/10/vodafone-proxy-breaks-some-javascript.html).

> and what is the convention in web applications once such user enters the site.

It ranges from [being built robustly](http://icant.co.uk/articles/pragmatic-progressive-enhancement/) to [failing horribly](http://www.webmonkey.com/2011/02/gawker-learns-the-hard-way-why-hash-bang-urls-are-evil/).

Answer (score 2):

Try creating simple version of your website with simple `html`, and fallback to it if `javascript` is disabled.

For example Gmail gives a message like following when js was disabled but...

> JavaScript must be enabled in order for you to use Gmail in standard
>   view. 
>   However, it seems JavaScript is either disabled or not supported by your 
>   browser. To use standard view, enable JavaScript by changing your browser 
>   options, then try again.

... Google Docs message was bit horrible and Google Calender messages didn't give any message.

See some stats from [YDN blog post](http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2010/10/how-many-users-have-javascript-disabled/).

But it is not about conventions or global js enabled statistics; focus, consider and research about **users of your site**

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is so used nowadays that the probability of having a user without JS enabled is really low. Users who disable JS normally know what they're doing, and will be able to understand why your web site doesn't work as it would is JS was enabled.

I wouldn't care about them.

Just make sure your web site can't be compromised by a user who disables JavaScript. For example, data validation should always be done at server-side. Relying on JS only to validate forms is dangerous.

Comment: "*I wouldn't care about them*"? Doesn't it depend on the nature of the site and constituency of users it hopes to attract? If you go to grc.com for example, the site is completely without Javascript with the recent exception of pages built to demonstrate it - *because the users there care about security*.

Comment: Reading the OP's question, his website is buit on JavaScript. His question is not "is it a good thing" or "should my site work even when JS is disabled". His question is "what should my website do when a user with JS disabled comes to my web site". My answer is thus: don't care about them: if they disabled JS, they did it on purpose and should be aware that by doing this, a whole lot of web sites will be non-functional. They must be used to it.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Answer (score -1):

<noscript style="color: red;"> Please, enable Javascript in your browser.</noscript>

See http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_noscript.asp